# Dynamic ID does not work in Eonasdan datetime picker

Tags: jquery, eonasdan-datetimepicker

```
**It's my cloned html element**
<pre>    
<input type="text" name="c_date[]" id="c_date1"class="form-control c_date comm"title='1'/><br/>
<input type="text" name="c_date[]" id="c_date2"class="form-control c_date comm"title='2'/><br/>
<input type="text" name="c_date[]" id="c_date3"class="form-control c_date comm"title='3'/></br/>
<input type="text" name="c_date[]" id="c_date4"class="form-control c_date comm"title='4'/>
</pre>
```

I have made unique id name by bellow code

```
<code>
$("table tr").each(function(index){
      var s=index+i;
      $(this).find("td .c_date").attr('title',index+i);
      $(this).find("td .c_date").attr('id','c_date'+s);
});
</code>
```

My datetime plugin code...............

```
<code>
       $("table tr td .c_date").each(function(){
            var val_num = $(this).attr('title');
            $("#c_date"+val_num).datetimepicker({
                useCurrent:true,
                format:'YYYY-MM-DD'
            });
        });
</code>
```

I have cloned a table row which containing some field.One of them "c_date" input field. it's will be more number. I want to set datetime picker in every field. above my code which does not work.........

Comment: can you please tell us in detail what you really want to do.

Comment: why don't you just bind on the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any cycle to attach plugin. This must work

```
$('.c_date').datetimepicker({
 useCurrent:true,
 format:'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```

**UPDATE 2**
This must work. First you must destroy all attached datetimepickers then attach it to class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker();
  $('input[name="cmdAddRow"]').on('click', function() {
   $('.datepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).data('DateTimePicker').destroy();
    });
    $curRow = $(this).parents('tr');
    rowIndex = $curRow.index() + 1;
    $newRow = $curRow.clone(true).find(".comm").val("").end();
    $curRow.after($newRow);
    $newRow.find('.datepicker').attr({
      id: rowIndex,
      title: rowIndex
    });
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker();
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="30px;">
      <span class="id"></span>
    </td>

   
    <td valign="top" width="150px">
      <input class="form-control comm wtime" type="number" step="any" id="latbox" value="" min="0" max="20" name="w_time[]">
      <!--<span class="error">*</span>-->
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="taskStatus[]" id="taskStatus" class="form-control comm">
        <option value="">Select Status</option>
        <option value="1">In Progress</option>
        <option value="2">Done</option>
        <option value="3">Pending</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="c_date[]" class="form-control datepicker comm" />
    </td>

    <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 25px;">
      <input class="btn btn-danger" id="remove" type="button" value="Remove">
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" name="cmdAddRow" value="Add">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if i run you code then datepicker show only first field.... it does not work another field..................

Comment: Edited answer. Try now

Comment: <pre>
        $('input[name="cmdAddRow"]').on('click', function(){
  $curRow = $(this).parent().parent();
  $newRow = $curRow.clone(true).find(".comm").val("").end();
  $curRow.after($newRow);
  serial_num();
 });
</pre>
It's my cloning script..........
I will click/focus on every field then I want to show datetime picker